# LAN and wifi not detecting after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, lan

Ubuntu is not detecting LAN sometimes.And 95 % of time it doesnot detect wifi.The network option says wifi are not in range even though they are

It usually happens when the ubuntu stays idle for long time.

But there are cases when I start my laptop and LAN is not detected.

It usually gets fixed when I reboot

I tried to do both of these things:
software and updates->Additional Drivers->Mark and unmark wireless card.

But none of them worked

Edit:
**lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280** gives:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
```

Comment: We need to know what wireless card you are using and what driver is installed. Please edit your question and add output from the two terminal commands: lspci | grep 802 and lsmod | grep 802

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280

Comment: Updated whatever you asked for.Please reply

Comment: come on dude!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can open up a terminal `CTRL+ALT+T` and install the broadcom-kernel-source.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then reboot.